# My ISP claims I have a virus

Tags: release-freya

Cox claims that I have a Zeus trojan/bot, despite the fact that I am on Elementary and that virus is designed for windows systems. Is that possible? What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

**Ignore them.**

It is most likely [a scam](http://www.zdnet.com/article/phone-scammers-target-pc-users-with-phony-virus-reports/). Very common here in Australia, usually bundled with threats that they will be *"forced to disconnect your internet"* etc. If in doubt you should phone your ISP directly to confirm.